# CSS Sprites not displaying inline

Tags: css, css-sprites

Some of my problem is I'm using the code from [this Lynda.com video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZzNlZCiaC4) - the Fireworks stuff is just as imported, the rest of the CSS I used his stuff, right down to the colours. Yet I've messed up somewhere and I don't know where.

Code is below. My sprites and hovers are showing up fine, but they're displaying as a block of buttons rather than a line. I've tried `float:left`, `display:block` in various places, even re-exported my sprites as horizontal rather than standard to no avail.

```
<code>
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:#000;
}

header nav {
width:100%;
background:#333;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
font:Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
height:98px;
border-bottom:12px solid black;
}

header nav ul {
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style:none;
}

header nav ul li {
position:relative;
width:110px;
height;90px
float:left;
border-bottom:12px solid #000;
border-left:1px solid #333
border-right:1px solid #666;
}

header nav ul li:hover {
border-bottom-color:#FFC926;
}

header nav ul li a {
width:110%;
color:#FFF;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline;
float:left;
padding-top:75px

}
.navsymbol li{    background:url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50029017/untitled%20folder/navsymbol.png") no-repeat;}
li.nav_Home{ width:342px; height:70px; background-position:-10px -10px; }
li.nav_Home:hover{ width:342px; height:70px; background-position:-362px -10px; }
li.nav_Contact{ width:342px; height:70px; background-position:-714px -10px; }
li.nav_Contact:hover{ width:342px; height:70px; background-position:-1066px -10px; }
li.nav_Design{ width:342px; height:70px; background-position:-1418px -10px; }
li.nav_Design:hover{ width:342px; height:70px; background-position:-1770px -10px; }
</code>
```

And html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
</head>

<body>
<header>
<nav>
<ul class="navsymbol">
<li class="nav_Home"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li class="nav_Design"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li class="nav_Contact"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your html as well?

Comment: ist the image not showing up at all? can you rename the "untitled folder" to untitle_folder or whatever just remove all spaces. some browser don't like spaces

Comment: The images are, almost surprisingly, showing up - it's just they're doing so in a block, rather than inline. I've done a bit of research which said CSS sprites were normally done in a block, but even changing it to display:inline wasn't helping (unless I was changing the wrong thing?)

Comment: What happened to the sprite? It seems to have gone 404?

Comment: I moved it out of the Dropbox folder as per the suggestion below, though all this moving about of images has now confused me as to what the files are linking to! I will create some new folders and link them up with the Dropbox, see if that works now.

Comment: Well my images are now uploaded and showing with a rollover! I had to use the horizontally-exported sprites, and add your code, but it's all working in Preview now! Thankyou so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have a typo:

```
header nav ul li {
position:relative;
width:110px;
height;90px /* should be- height:90px;*/
float:left;
border-bottom:12px solid #000;
border-left:1px solid #333
border-right:1px solid #666;
}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/P7aWC/3/)** Apparently the sprite has gone 404, so the example isn't working now...

Comment: Ah - sorry, I've been trying to move stuff into local files so I broke it! I'll put it back where it was :)

Comment: @AishaC did you fix the typo?

Comment: I fixed it, but haven't moved the new image file over yet - once I've finished dyeing my hair I'll be able to get that back up and hopefully get this silly menu issue sorted! :)

Answer (score -1):

change

```
header nav ul li {
position:relative;
width:110px;
height;90px /* should be- height:90px;*/
float:left;
border-bottom:12px solid #000;
border-left:1px solid #333
border-right:1px solid #666;
}
```

to

```
header nav ul li {
position:relative;
width:110px;
height:90px;
float:left;
border-bottom:12px solid #000;
border-left:1px solid #333
border-right:1px solid #666;
}
```

and insert to css file

```
.navsymbol:after{
    clear:both;
}
.navsymbol:after,.navsymbol:before{
    display:table;
    content:"";
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding empty pseudo-elements?

Comment: Empty pseudo-elements aside, the rest of this code worked (still working out the best place to host my images, as the https thing is also an issue) - though, I'm not entirely sure why?

Comment: @AishaC the working bit looks to have been directly copied from my answer... the empty pseudo-elements are effectively useless...

Comment: I did think so! Well if it's your code, thankyou very much :) I have removed the Tick mark from the post in response to his stolen code.

Answer (score -2):

Use `http` on the place of `https` in background url
**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/P7aWC/2/)**

```
.navsymbol li{    background:url("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50029017/untitled%20folder/navsymbol.png") no-repeat;}
```

Comment: Hmm, gave it a go, but then it loses the sprites completely as they're being hosted on my own Dropbox until I can get it working. Works with the https in Preview in Browser and live, but just in a block.

Comment: but you can not use https in background url. so just download image and put it in local folder like image

Comment: Wasn't me - I will have a go with your JSfiddle when I'm back on my laptop with my source files. Thanks for your time!